# How to make a cross browser, W3C valid, semantic, non-javascript ROUND corner?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a *cross-browser* (FF3, IE6, Safari, Opera), *W3C valid* (HTML and CSS both), *stretchable* (horizontally vertically), *without JavaScript* and with *Semantic* and lesser HTML markup **Round CORNER**. *Images can be used for IE6.*

I've tried and tested many techniques available on community. But everything has one of the problems mentioned above . If anyone knows what I want please share with me?

Remember I want to make it without any type of JavaScript, jquery or any type of js.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The two major rendering engines have supported CSS3 for quite some time, which makes rounded corners as simple as:

```
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
```

Of course, this doesn't have any effect on IE6 or 7 <del>(it works in IE8)</del> or 8 so you need to implement the nasty stacked division with images for the corners, which doesn't fit your semantic requirement.

I'm not a fan of display-hacks that involve javascript or css-hacks - so I use CSS3 and check that the squared-off version in IE7 looks acceptable. I've been doing this for a while as IE never used to support PNG transparency either - which meant you couldn't nicely overlay a rounded corner image on a patterned background. IE8 is a big improvement, so the problem does start to go away - but I understand your desire to make it work on IE6 and above.

**UPDATE: Various CSS3 bits and pieces that were originally planned to be included in IE8 were actually removed from the final release. border-radius was one of the victims.**

Comment: Thx for ur answer, I know IE6 solution needed Js or images. i want to make a round corner with images but want to use lesser images, markup and semantic way.

Comment: @Sohnee - you should put your update into your answer where you can be sure no one will miss it.

Comment: @Sohnee: Have you tested that this doesn't work in IE8 either?

Comment: FTR, IE6 always supported PNG transparency, but only on dithered PNGs, which is what people should have been using on the web anyway, and should still use to reduce filesize.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is you can't do everything you want without CSS3 - which isn't implemented in any but the latest versions of browsers.

So, the answer is to either use CSS3 (as detailed by Sohnee above) or learn to love the javascript / divs / images solutions. And make sure it displays ok when a browser with none of these looks at it...

Answer (score 3):

The best solution to date is [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/).

It allows you to add rounded corners to IE using CSS.

You can use CSS border-radius for all the other browers, and CSS3Pie for IE.

It uses the IE-specific `behavior` style, so isn't standard CSS, but it does mean you get properly semantic HTML (no spurious divs for layout), and you don't need to worry about JQuery plug ins either.

It is Javascript (of sorts), but only needs to be run on IE; all other browsers will use normal CSS to deal with it, and won't even load the IE-specific code.

(btw IE9 now does support border-radius... but of course, IE6/7/8 are all still out there and will be for some time to come)

Comment: The question is "non-javascript"

Comment: @Jitendra - he also specified semantic HTML. The fact is that IE6/7/8 can't do it without either Javascript or extra markup. CSS3Pie is by far the least obtrusive solution.

Answer (score 1):

This should allow you to get the desired result. Old stacked DIVs method, with a single big background image .You have to create a very big background image, e.g. 2000 x 2000 pixels, where you will draw a rectangle with rounded corners. I recommend to save it as a .GIF with transparent background to ensure compatibility with IE6, since you want to avoid JavaScript. Note that borders, in the example, are just to help figuring out where element are appearing and can be removed.

I tested it on IE6, IE7, Firefox 2 and 3, Safari and Opera. Hope this helps.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .RoundRectInside
    {
      width: 100%;
      background: url(BigBackground.gif) top left no-repeat;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .RoundRectOutside
    {
      width: 20em;
      height: 20em;
      background: url(BigBackground.gif) bottom left no-repeat;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
    }

    .RoundRectTopRight
    {
      float: right;
      /* Width and Height should correspond to width and height of rounded corner */
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      background: url(BigBackground.gif) top right no-repeat;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
    }

    .RoundRectBottomRight
    {
      float: right;
      /* Width and Height should correspond to width and height of rounded corner */
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      background: url(BigBackground.gif) bottom right no-repeat;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="RoundRectOutside">
    <div class="RoundRectInside">
      <div>Content goes here</div>
      <div class="RoundRectTopRight"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="RoundRectBottomRight"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thx for this i will try thisbut i 've a good solution with ome very small image only but in this color border is not possible.http://apptools.com/examples/roundedbox.php

Comment: please give me a live link of your example . i didn't understand properly . i tested but not working is already show a red border on box

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any server where I can upload it. However,
as I wrote in my answer, red border appears because I put a "border" 
attribute in CSS, to help figuring out the position of the elements. I modified my post and removed the border, try copying it now.

Comment: how to make image for this can i make with border. right now it's not working after edit

Comment: You have to create a GIF image with an application like Photoshop, and put a rectangle with round borders in it (it has to be as large as the image itself). Save it with transparent background and you're done.

Comment: @Deigo: The image could take 40 seconds to download for some visitors (18% of US citizens use connections slower than 768 kilobits per second, as of 2009). See also: (1) http://websiteoptimization.com/services/analyze (2) http://www.physorg.com/news170447728.html (3) http://goo.gl/qdvW

Comment: Dave, I created a 2000x2000 pixels GIF and the file size was around 10 KB. I don't think it could take 40 seconds to download it...

Comment: For completeness, I made a test with a PNG file as well. With 32 bit color depth (excessive for a border, a good result can be obtained with just 8 bit), the file size is approximately 60 KB.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the technique described [here](http://www.ditchnet.org/wp/2007/02/10/expandable-widget-tutorial/) (it's for an Apple Dashboard Widget, but the HTML/CSS should be the same). It uses nine images and doesn't require any JavaScript.

Steve

Comment: It only uses JavaScript for the animation part—the rounded corners are done with just HTML/CSS. But yes, it does require many divs.

Comment: <div class="round">

Content

</div>

i want this type of markup

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by semantic or stretchable rounded corners, but you can use the CSS border-radius attributes for Webkit and Firefox, and simply use a combination of PNG images and [this HTML Component](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/), which adds PNG alpha-channel support to IE6.

Comment: i want to do without javascript for IE

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the minimal non js rounded corner technique for ie6/7 requires 2 small images (top and bottom) and 1 extra div for fixed width boxes, and 3 small images (bottom, left and right) and 3 extra divs for a variable width box.

Fixed width

```
<div class="box">
<div class="bottom">
gjkgjk
</div>
</div>

.box {background:url(image to round off the top) top left no-repeat:padding:0;}
.box .bottom {background:url(image to round off the bottom) bottom left no-repeat:margin:0;width:100px}
```

Variable width

```
<div class="box">
<div class="top-right">
<div class="bottom-left">
<div class="bottom-right">
gjkgjk
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

.box {background:url(image to round off the top-left) top left no-repeat:padding:0;}
.box .right{background:url(image to round off the top-right) top right no-repeat:padding:0;margin:0;}
.box .bottom-left {background:url(image to round off the bottom-left) bottom left no-repeat:margin:0;padding:0;}
.box .bottom-right {background:url(image to round off the bottom-right) bottom right no-repeat:margin:0;padding:0;}
```

If you want a rounded border rather than just a rounded solid background the above can be tweaked using border, negative margin, position relative/absolute, width and background-image position so it works, but can't remember off the top of my head how.

Comment: i need stretchable so #1 is not for me and for #2 solution i found a better way , see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I've found till now.

http://apptools.com/examples/roundedbox.php

It is a cross browser, W3C valid and use only **one image** . but we can't make border with this.

This solution for a fixed width witdth border.

it use little markup `
Content

`
with valid css,html
http://www.askthecssguy.com/examples/roundedCorners/index.html

Comment: If you take a look at my method, you can do it with less markup.

Comment: Just a note: the example at *askthecssguy.com* doesn't scale very well, as it uses fixed widths. Therefore, it's not really "stretchable".

Answer (score 0):

If you use a PNG8 with alpha transparency, images can have transparency in IE6. The caveats are that you can only have fully transparent or opaque images (anything in between will just be rendered 100% transparent) and that you can't use a large color palette or gradients.

Depending on your design, there is a possible workaround or you can use this in conjunction with the PNG8 option above. If your background is simple, you can just match anything outside the corners with the background. Using this technique, you could easily make do with a single image for your corners if you make use of sprites. The markup would look similar to the following:

```
<div id="content">
     <span class="lt"></span>
     <span class="rt"></span>
     <span class="lb"></span>
     <span class="rb"></span>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#content {position:relative;}

/*These styles are generic and can be reused over multiple corner types*/
.lt, .rt, .lb, .rb{
    background:url(../images/button_corners.png) no-repeat;
    width:5px;
    height:5px;
    position:absolute;
}
.lt, .rt{top:0px;}
.rt, .rb{right:0px;}
.lt, .lb{left:0px;}
.rb, .lb{bottom:0px;}

/*The following would be used specifically for #content, but you could reuse a different part of the same image for a different container or button */

#content .lt{background-position:-200px 0px;}
#content .rt{background-position:-245px 0px;}
#content .lb{background-position:-200px -45px;}
#content .rb{background-position:-245px -45px;}
```

There are advantages and disadvantages to this approach:

**Advantages**

It's cross-browser, it works with liquid and fixed layouts, and you can use it for menu items (hover will work in IE6 for links) or containers, it doesn't *require* JavaScript, and using a CSS sprite, you can do it with a single image, even with multiple corner types.

**Disadvantages**

It won't work with every layout, borders can be tricky or ugly, it adds a few extra elements into the markup, and if you use it for a link item with a hover effect, IE6 has a hover flicker that can only be solved with a little bit of JavaScript. However, that JavaScript is only one line and can be included in a conditional comment:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache",false,true);</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using Javascript for just IE, you can use conditional comments and Javascript to dynamically insert VML roundrects that can do what you want (or just use static conditionally commented VML).  CSS3 border radius covers Gecko, WebKit and KHTML.  Opera requires an SVG background image.

Here's an example pulled from one of my projects: http://entr0py.org/misc/reader/basic/

I'm told it still has some WebKit bugs relating to background coloring, but it works fine in everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I recently had to overcome the same problem, A resizeable widget with rounded corners, inside border, drop shadow and a gradient background. It also has to work on all browsers (IE6 included).

Assuming you are using photoshop and look after your source files properly it is fairly easy. In total it requires 4 images (up to 7 depending on how you support IE6), these can all be sliced from the original photoshop file so its pretty easy.

Check out the link below.

http://thatguynamedandy.com/blog/css-widget-rounded-corner-gradient-drop-shadow

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few methods that work across all browsers:

- [BorderStyles](http://battletech.hopto.org/html_tutorials/rounded_css_borders/more_styles.html)
- [Snazzy Borders](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/snazzy2.html)
- [Chunky Borders](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/chunky.html)
- [Bullet Corners](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/curves.html)