# how to make edges round in CSS?

Tags: html, css, border, rounding, paragraph

I am beginner coder in web design so I have a fairly amateur question to ask. I have created a box of text but I don't know how to make the edges round rather than rectangular. I know that CSS functions on rectangular borders. If possible, I would also like to add a slight shadow beneath the box, I'm not sure how to implement this also. Here is my code specifically for the box section:

```
#wrapper{
border: solid 1px #eeeeee;
}
```

"#wrapper" refers to a piece of php code in another document. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rounded Corners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812301/rounded-corners)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `border-radius` and `box-shadow`.

```
#wrapper {
    border: solid 1px #eee;
    border-radius:10px; /* round corners */
    box-shadow:0px 3px 5px 5px #000; /* add shadow */
}
```

Here are the parameters for each...

```
border-radius:(radius of border corners)
box-shadow:(horizontal offset) (vertical offset) (blur) (spread) (color)
```

You may wish to prefix your CSS3 properties with `-webkit` and `-moz` to increase compatibility with older browsers.

Comment: Should be noted that this doesn't work in IE8 and older and that a webkit vendor prefix for box-shadow (-webkit-box-shadow:) is useful if one wants to support Android and the previous versions of Safari on OS X and iOS.

Answer (score 2):

```
#wrapper {
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px; /* Saf3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android ≤1.6 */
  -moz-border-radius: 12px; /* FF1-3.6 */
  border-radius: 12px; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, Saf5, Chrome, FF4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
  /* useful if you don't want a bg color from leaking outside the border: */
  -moz-background-clip: padding; -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

check [this](http://css3please.com/) out!

Answer (score 1):

For browsers which do not support `border-radius`, you can use [roundies.js](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/).